# get list of all commands run in past with sudo apt-get install in terminal

Tags: apt, sudo, history

As per command  `history` in Ubuntu terminal we can see all previous command we run on system.
I want to know how can we get all previous command which starts with some words/characters.
Example : i want to list of all commands I run using `sudo apt-get install`  or `pip install`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite as particular as what you're asking but it's clean and should do the job:

```
grep install ~/.bash_history
```

By default the bash history is only 500 lines long so if you use the terminal as much as me, that's probably not going to show you that much.

A second chance is offered to us via the auth logs.

```
zgrep -Eo 'apt-get install.*' /var/log/auth*
```

Of course, this only works for apt-get. If you're using pip as root, you could also use it for that but in my experience, that's less common (you should be working in a virtualenv).